# Exception handling quandry

Tags: c#

I am throwing a new exception when a database row is not found.

Class that was called:

```
public ProfileBO retrieveProfileByCode(string profileCode)
{
    return retrieveSingleProfile("profile_code", profileCode);
}

private ProfileBO retrieveSingleProfile(string termField, string termValue)
{
    ProfileBO profile = new ProfileBO();
    //Query string is temporary.  Will make this a stored procedure.
    string queryString = " SELECT * FROM GamePresenterDB.gp.Profile WHERE " + termField + " = '" + termValue + "'";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(App.getConnectionString()))
    {
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.Read())
        {
            profile = castDataReadertoProfileBO(reader, profile);
        }
        else
        {
            // No record was selected.  log it and throw the exception (We'll log it later, for now just write to console.)
            Console.WriteLine("No record was selected from the database for method retrieveSingleProfile()");
            throw new InvalidOperationException("An exception occured.  No data was found while trying to retrienve a single profile.");
        }

        reader.Close();
    }
    return profile;
}
```

However, when I catch the exception in the calling class, 'e' is now null. What am I doing wrong? I believe this works fine in Java, so C# must handle this differently.

Calling class:

```
private void loadActiveProfile()
{
    try
    {
        ProfileBO profile = profileDAO.retrieveProfileByCode(p.activeProfileCode);
        txtActiveProfileName.Text = profile.profile_name;
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Please show all relevant parts of your code, especially how you actually call the method that throws the exception.

Comment: Side note, you are not disposing command and reader. You should wrap those in `using` also, because they do implement `IDisposable`

Comment: ok I updated the question.

Comment: Where is e null? Are you even reaching the catch block?

Comment: You tag your code with `wpf`, but output to a `Console`, is this intentional? You might want `Debug.WriteLine(...)` instead. In either case, check my answer below, although, I think Kallen's response answers your question directly.

Comment: Check for a "generic" `Exception`. Basically add another `catch (Esxception e)` block. This is generally a good practice to catch something unexpected. Put a breakpoint in it and see if something else is thrown...

Comment: Are you sure the exception is thrown? Comment out the rest of the code in `retrieveSingleProfile` and leave just the line throwing the exception (so it's definitely thrown), what happens now?

Comment: @nurchi: only check generic exceptions for debugging purposes however. You do not want to write code that swallows Fatal Exceptions.

Comment: This whole code should indeed work a you expect. The Stacktrace should look accordingly. As you do not have any other try/catch bloks that might interfere, the only idea I have is that the Exception is not thrown at all. I think catch does a "is" check on the Exception class. So no block could be entered if Exception was null (`null is InvalidOperationException` has to always be false).

Comment: @Christopher, I agree, I meant to write that, but I can only edit my comment within the first 5 mins. And what's wrong with swallowing fatal exceptions :P

Comment: @nurchi: It is only a deadly sin of Exception Handling. No, not much wrong :)

Comment: @Christopher, haha, I guess :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now all the code has been put in the question, you can move the try catch outside of your 'loadActiveProfile' method and place it into 'retrieveSingleProfile'.

```
private void loadActiveProfile()
{

        ProfileBO profile = profileDAO.retrieveProfileByCode(p.activeProfileCode);
        txtActiveProfileName.Text = profile.profile_name;
    }
```

removed the try catch^

```
private ProfileBO retrieveSingleProfile(string termField, string termValue)
    {
      try {


        ProfileBO profile = new ProfileBO();
       //Query string is temporary.  Will make this a stored procedure.
        string queryString = " SELECT * FROM GamePresenterDB.gp.Profile WHERE " + termField + " = '" + termValue + "'";

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(App.getConnectionString()))
        {
            connection.Open();

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.Read())                
            {
                profile = castDataReadertoProfileBO(reader, profile);
            } 
            else
            {
                // No record was selected.  log it and throw the exception (We'll log it later, for now just write to console.)
                Console.WriteLine("No record was selected from the database for method retrieveSingleProfile()");
                throw new InvalidOperationException("An exception occured.  No data was found while trying to retrienve a single profile.");
            }

            reader.Close();
        }
        return profile;
       }
      catch(InvalidOperationException e)
      { 

      }
    }
```

Added try catch in the correct place.

Comment: you beat me to it by 2 minutes :)

Comment: @nurchi haha gotta catch em all!

Answer (score 2):

You need to step *into* the `catch` block for `e` to be set to the thrown `InvalidOperationException`:

```
catch (System.InvalidOperationException e)
{
int breakPoint = 0; //<- set a breakpoint here.
    //Either you reach the breakpoint and have an InvalidOperationException, or you don't reach the breakpoint.
   MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
}
```

Also make sure that the `InvalidOperationException` you throw is actually a `System.InvalidOperationException` and not some custom type of yours called "InvalidOperationException".

Comment: This must have been the issue. An empty catch block did raise my eyebrows, but I thought the content was left blank for brevity... Rule #1: never assume anything. Lesson learned, again... :(

Comment: @nurchi It doesn't matter if inside the catch block is empty, it will still hit the catch and 'e' will still have the exception.

The inside of the catch could be empty and this code would still work.

Comment: Interesting, then, I guess, the exception wasn't being thrown, but why was `e` `null` then?

Answer (score 0):

Like @Clemens said, you need to show all the relevant code.

As a quick test, this works just fine:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Throwing error");
            ThrowException();
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }

    static void ThrowException()
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Blah blah blah");
    }
}
```